# SPO site collection app catalog and custom scripting

Tags: spfx

Do we need to enable custom scripting in site collection before setting up app catalog in site collection?

Thanks,
Praveen Kumar P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Custom Scripting is disabled by default.

Taken from [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/12/how-to-enable-custom-script-in-sharepoint-online.html):

> By default, Custom Scripts are disabled in SharePoint Online for
> security reasons. So the below features are blocked when the custom
> scripting is disabled:

> Many web parts including content editor, script editor, etc are
> disabled.
>
> 1. Uploading files that potentially include scripts are blocked
> 2. SharePoint Designer script changes not allowed
> 3. Save Site as Template,
> 4. Save document library as template links disabled Solution Gallery,
>    Sandbox Solutions, Theme Gallery, HTML Field Settings are not
>    available
> 5. All other script-related featured are turned off So,

> To fix
> the above problems, we need to enable custom script settings. Here is
> how to enable custom script in SharePoint Online.

If you are looking for something of the above functionalities, you can enable Custom Scripts, although you should NOT since it's an outdated way.

In order to create an App Catalog you should follow the [official guide by MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog#step-1-create-the-app-catalog-site-collection)

There's another option of Site Collection App Catalog, which installation is described by this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-site-collection-app-catalog-for-particular-site-collection-level-solution/)

Comment: Thank you @jimas13. Since enabling scripting is an outdated way, I assume we all need to follow spfx way for developing web parts. So we do not need to enable scripting in  particular site collection before we add app catalog to it right?

Comment: If you are asking wether Custom Scripts are needed for SPFX web parts to be run, no, this option is not needed. Enabling an App Catalog for a specific Site Collection is documented in this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-site-collection-app-catalog-for-particular-site-collection-level-solution/